# How to resolve 404 error on deploying .net core web API

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, webdeploy

Hi I have done following steps while hosting my .net core web API in IIS of my laptop. But when I browse the URL I get 404 error.

Sample URL: http://localhost/Myapp/api/user

Help will be much appreciated! If need any further info let me know.

Steps:

1. Install Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle 2.2.5
2. Hosted web api in IIS with defaul 80 port number without any hostname
3. Created new application pool with No MANAGED CODE as .NET CLR Version.

Comment: did you publish your site?

Comment: double check that this is not a 500 error hiding behind an attempt to redirect to a an error page that doesn't exist hence the 404.

Comment: I don't have error page .. however what could be the reason of not getting output ... It's works fine in visual studio

Comment: Yes jalpa.. it had published on local host iis. .

Answer (score 1):

To host .NET Core Web API in IIS follow below steps:

- Publish the Web APIs to Your Local Folder
  [image]
  for example, D:\testcoreapi
- Install Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting Bundle File
  [ASP.NET Core Module Configuration Reference](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246)
- Open IIS Create One Application Pool of No Managed Code
  [image]
- Create Web Site to point to the local folder of your published.

Note:
Do not forget to select an application pool which you created before with no managed setting.
[image]

If you are still not able to browse the site select your site from connection node in iis.
right click on site and select "Explore" and make sure that you select right folder.

[image]

For more detail you could follow the below article:
https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

Regards,
Jalpa